# E-Mail Forwarding using Azure DNS

Tags: azure, email, dns, cpanel, forwarding

## Is there no E-Mail Forwarding in Azure DNS?

I *(regretfully)* bought a custom domain using Azure and I want to set up e-mail forwarders to various custom domain email-addresses to support forwarding to any number of email-providers and different addresses.

Through the Azure Portal, I tried navigating to somewhere where I could administer the domain and I ended up [here](https://dcc.secureserver.net/domains/), some webapp outside of Azure called the *"Advanced Management Portal"*.

Here I'm expecting to be able to set up e-mail forwarding to different e-mail addresses just like in cPanel - another common DNS management tool.

Inside the *"Advanced Management Portal"* (outside of Azure) I can find forwarding for hostnames and subdomains. But nothing for E-mail?

I'm looking for something like..

```
info1@customdomain.com -> myinfo1@gmail.com

info2@customdomain.com -> myinfo2@gmail.com
```

Any monkey could do this in cPanel. The so called "Advanced Management Portal" doesn't feel advanced at all. It offers very little, contains dead links and looks very unprofessional.

So, how do solve my use case using Azure DNS? Do I need to create MX records within the DNS and point to Azure VMs handling the email? This seems so overkill?

I tried the [FAQ](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/08/FAQ-App-Service-Domain-and-Custom-Domains.html) but it doesn't contain anything relevant

All the best,
Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS have nothing to do with emails (except `MX` records). So you should do this kind of redirection in to your mail server. And yes, to do such redirections you need `MX` records and mail server.

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased your domain through Google, there is a mechanism to configure email forwarding.

https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?authuser=0&hl=en#emailForwarding

I use Google DNS and the email forwarding feature. There is documentation in how to configure with custom DNS like Azure DNS too, but I have never tried this.

https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9428703?authuser=0